# Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used. User? user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(

Tags: flutter

Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.     User? user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(

```
User? user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
 void signUp() async {
    String email = _email.text;
    String password = _password.text;

    User? user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);

    if (user == null) {
      print("User is succesfully created");
      Navator.pushNamed(context, "/Home");
```

Comment: this is a compile time error or Run time error?

Comment: This isn't valid syntax.... did something get lost in a cut-n-paste?

Answer (score 0):

You don't needs to use async method inside of signInWithEmailAndPassword method.
Please check out the Firebase auth official documentation for the implementation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

```
UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
```

From the official document of Firebase Auth.

```
const auth = getAuth();
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```